# What do I need to do in order to ask, if an pointer to an abstract class in instance of a child class?

Tags: class, object, pointers, c++-cli, instanceof

I need some help to understand everything correctly.

I want to check a pointer to a abstract class if it is instance of a specific child class.

I have one abstract class "kunde" and two child classes "firmenkunde" and "privatkunde" who inherit the methods of kunde.

In order to search by "int knr" (int customer number) I use as return type a pointer to "kunde".

Within the database class I get back the "kdstatus" and use

```
kunde * kd = new privatkunde(0);
```

if the status is PK or new firmenkunde(0) if it would be FK. 
The abstract class kunde doesn't have any attribute I could use to save the status.

This way I did hope to be able to ask, if the returned pointer would be an instance of the class privatkunde or firmenkunde. But I did not found any method to do this.

```
 MessageBox::Show(marshal_as<String^>(typeid(kd).name()));
```

I did ask the typeid name but this only returns "class kunde *" and is not what I want to know.

Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: This is not C++.

Comment: Have a look at `virtual` functions.

Comment: Please what is not C++? You mean the MessageBox this is from .Net because we use Windows Forms for the gui

Comment: Add a variable (say ID) in the base class;  vary ID for each child class.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) for this.

An example:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Parent();

    virtual void do_thing()= 0;
};

class Child1: public Parent
{
public:
    void do_thing() override
    {
        //...
    }
};

class Child2: public Parent
{
public:
    void do_thing() override
    {
        //...
    }
};

void use_parent(Parent* p)
{
    auto c1_ptr = dynamic_cast<Child1*>(p);
    if(c1_ptr != nullptr)
    {
        // p is a Child1

        do_thing_with_child1(c1_ptr);

    }
    auto c2_ptr = dynamic_cast<Child2*>(p);
    if(c2_ptr != nullptr)
    {
        // p is a Child2
        do_thing_with_child2(c2_ptr);
    }
}
```

While this works, it becomes difficult to maintain if you have multiple child classes. You have to remember to add a case for each new child class you define.

A better way to structure something like this would be to use the "Tell, don't ask" concept when designing your object-oriented systems. A great write-up on this concept can be found [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html).

Comment: I guess it's typo s but the syntax for dynamic cast is a bit off, also note that dynamic cast requires rtti.

Comment: Okay do I understand is correct that I would need a method in the child class to work around my problem?

Comment: But how do I call the child method? If I am correct I can not call the methods of a child from a pointer of the parent.

Comment: The pointer obtained from `dynamic_cast<T*>` is of type T*. So you can call the method on the pointer obtained from the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeid` as you mentioned. Using the polymorphism, you can write:

```
kunde * kd = new privatkunde(0);
if(typeid(kd) == typeid(privatkunde))
{
    // This is a privatkunde objet
}
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/operator==/) to have more explanation.

The problem you encounter is that your `kunde` class is not polymorphic. As commented by @George, see how the virtual methods work.

I hope it can help.

Comment: But typeid(kd).name returns class kunde * even if I did think it should be privatkunde *

Comment: Yes because you didn't make the base class polymorphic. Check the link I gave to you, there is a good example.